# i made trigger to update data when people make action in form

Tags: oracle, triggers

trigger code good but when make action this error appear

> error ORA-04091: table OR_HR.SELL is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.

trigger code

```
create or replace TRIGGER  "QUALITY_EDIT" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Sell
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE  DRUG
SET QUANTITY =
(SELECT (DRUG.QUANTITY - SELL.QUANTITY )  FROM Sell
JOIN Drug
ON SELL.DRUG_ID = DRUG.DRUG_ID) ;
END;
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: your trigger is involving same table to which it belongs. When table is modified , it is mutating. This is illegal. You simply can't do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select from table which is just being updated (or inserted into), it is *mutating* and trigger can't see it.

Lucky you, you don't have to select from `sell`, use something like this (the `:new` pseudorecord) instead:

```
create or replace trigger quality_edit
  after insert or update on sell
  for each row
begin
  update drug d set
    d.quantity = d.quantity - :new.quantity
    where d.drug_id = :new.drug_id;
end;
/
```